# Bat file to search and return results based on part of file name

Tags: batch-file, search, cmd

I've seen similar questions answered but due to my lack of skills I cant quite make them work the way that I want them to.

Basically I would like a bat file that asks for a user input which is then used to list all of the **folders** in a predefined directory.

For example, user inputs **patt**, it will scan the directory and return all folders that contain patt eg.

**patt**erson1

**patt**erson2

**patt**erson_documents

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
set /p pattern=Enter pattern
cd <your folder path>
dir /b /A:D *%pattern%*
```

`/b` will return only the file/folder names and `/A:D` will restrict search to directories only. If you want to recursively search in subdirectories, you can add `/S`switch i.e. `dir /b /A:D /S *patt*`

Comment: perfect, thank you. My brain just cant put commands together like that!

Comment: To make this batch perfect you should read about delayed expansion

Comment: I would add the switch `/D` to the `cd` command just in case `<your folder path>` is on a drive other than the current one...

Comment: @Marged, what's the point of delayed expansion in this context here?

Comment: @aschipfl OP seems to be at starter level when it comes to batchfiles so it is a good idea to learn about what can happen to a batch when bad or even malicious input is passed to it

Comment: @Marged, alright, so it would be a good idea to share your thoughts with the OP... ;-)